# Using JdbcTemplate to insert large CLOB's into Oracle fails

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, clob

I am interfacing with an Oracle database via Spring's `JdbcTemplate` utility class, and I have tried these two variants of code:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO my_table (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)", title, content);
```

-- or --

```
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        OraclePreparedStatement ps = (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, title);
        ps.setStringForClob(2, content);
        return ps;
    }
});
```

Where `title` is a traditional `VARCHAR2`, and `content` is a `CLOB`.

Either of these alternatives work for smaller values for `content`.  However, when I have larger amounts of `content`, nothing gets inserted into the `CLOB` column.

Interestingly enough, in both cases, `title` gets updated.  It's as if the query just ignores `content` if there's too much, but never throws an error.

Does anybody know how I should solve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Per the answer from @GreyBeardedGeek, I tried using `OracleLobHandler` and `DefaultLobHandler`, to the same effect.  Things work until my `CLOB`'s reach a certain size.

I also tried the following code, again to the same effect:

```
Connection conn = db.getDataSource().getConnection();
CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
clob.setString(1, myString);

OraclePreparedStatement ps = (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE my_table SET blob = ?");
ps.setCLOB(1, clob);
ps.execute();
```

I'm baffled as to why every one of these methods would work for smaller `CLOB`'s, but then suddenly break for large ones.  Is there some type of configuration in the DB that I'm missing?  Or is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I feel pretty silly.  As it turns out, even this simple code was storing the `CLOB` correctly:

```
jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE my_table SET title = ?, content = ? WHERE id = ?", getTitle(), getContentString(), getId());
```

The issue was my code that retrieved the `CLOB` back from the database.  The following is my speculation based on my code (and the fix): it seems as though smaller `CLOB`'s get cached in memory, and can be read at a later time (namely, after the connection is closed, they can still be read).  However, for larger `CLOB`'s, they must be read while the connection is still open.

For me, this meant the fix was as simple as reading the `CLOB`'s contents as soon as it was available to my object.  In my case, I'm not really worried about memory issues, because I don't expect that my `CLOB`'s will contain inordinately sized contents, and so reading the value into memory immediately is an acceptable approach.

Comment: So to clarify, (I have to deal with this issue as well) jdbc templates handle clobs already by just passing them as they are to the update query?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat - I believe the answer to your question is yes.  It's been awhile since I looked at this code, but the issue was that my call to `getContentString()` was delayed, and could no longer read the CLOB.  The solution was to cache the CLOB immediately upon its first availability.  I hope that wasn't confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has, for as long as I can remember, required special handling for BLOBs and CLOBs.
Spring JDBC has org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler for setting the value of BLOBs and CLOBs.

There's a pretty good full example of how to use it at http://techdive.in/spring/spring-handling-blobclob but basically,  instead of `ps.setStringForClob`, you would do

`oracleLobHandler.getLobCreator().setClobAsString(ps, 2, content);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've updated my question with details.  Unfortunately using `OracleLobHandler` (and even `DefaultLobHandler`) didn't work.  I also tried just getting the connection and then doing things "manually" to the same effect.  Could this be misconfiguration in the database rather than an issue with my code?  I'm starting to run out of ideas here...

Comment: if this were the case none of the CLOBs would work. OP has them working for some cases, so I don't see how this would be an issue.

Answer (score -3):

`SqlLobValue(String content)` can be used for CLOB.

Follow the link:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/SqlLobValue.html

.